# iOS build failed with `ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated`

Tags: ios, flutter, bitcode, codemagic

I have following error when building iOS with CodeMagic.

```
    Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode archive done.                                         14.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/m7/h1mg7c7x40ddjz6mxjxm3htr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.o4LK5x/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirDQZb2l/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/builder/programs/flutter_2_10_1/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/Flutter.framework/Flutter' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/builder/programs/flutter_2_10_1/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/Flutter.framework/Flutter'
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/m7/h1mg7c7x40ddjz6mxjxm3htr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.o4LK5x/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirDQZb2l/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Error (Xcode): Bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/builder/programs/flutter_2_10_1/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/Flutter.framework/Flutter' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/builder/programs/flutter_2_10_1/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

To solve this issue, I changed ENABLE_BITCODE value to YES in project.pbxproj but the same error occurs.

```
97C147071CF9000F007C117D /* Release */ = {
        isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
        baseConfigurationReference = 7AFA3C8E1D35SGSDC0083082E /* Release.xcconfig */;
        buildSettings = {
            ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
            CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES;
            CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 4;
            DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = 56KC6SGDDR;
            ENABLE_BITCODE = YES;
            INFOPLIST_FILE = Runner/Info.plist;
            LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                "$(inherited)",
                "@executable_path/Frameworks",
            );
            PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.aaa.bbbMarket;
            PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
            SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = "Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h";
            SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0;
            VERSIONING_SYSTEM = "apple-generic";
        };
        name = Release;
    };
```

And my CodeMagic setting for building iOS is below.
[my settings in CodeMagic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRDRH.png)

Our app has already been first built with xcode and updated to the apple store, and we are setting up additional CI/CD now.

How do I solve this? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think the solution is opposite you need to **disable bitcode** because Flutter doesn't use it. You can do it by editing your Podfile to something like this:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
      build_configuration.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

you can find more details here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78589

Comment: For anyone trying to run this command, there is a missing single quote at the end of ENABLE_BITCODE - just make sure to add it.

Answer (score 4):

[image]I had a similar problem.
My solution was to goto Xcode-Product-Scheme-edit scheme-  make sure that the archive schemas build configuration is set to Release.
Mine was for some reason set to debug.